# Galois theory and the connection to prime numbers

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $F \subseteq E $ be a finite Galois extension with $G =\operatorname{ gal}( E : F )$. If $p$ is a prime integer and $p \mid [ E : F ] $, show that there exists an intermediate field extension $F \subseteq K \subseteq E$ such that $[E:K] = p$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $|G|=[E:F]$, hence using [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), there exists $H\leqslant G$ of cardinality $p$. Therefore, using [Galois' correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), there exists an intermediate field $K(=E^H)$ such that $[E:K]=|H|$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was thinking among those lines and I just wanted to confirm it. Is it always true that $|G|=[E:F]$?

Comment: No. In fact, if $E/F$ is a finite field extension, then $|G|\leqslant [E:F]$ with equality if and only if $E/F$ is Galois.

Comment: So how come you said that $|G|=[E:F]$. Sorry for asking so many questions but I just started studying Galois theory and I want to understand this as best as I can.

Comment: Read carefully what I have written and what are the assumptions of your exercise : $E/F$ is Galois, so everything is fine!

Comment: Sorry again for the confusion. If  $E/F$ is Galois, all we know is that G|⩽[E:F]. How can we show that in this case it is actually $G|=[E:F]$ and not $G|<[E:F]$

Comment: That is a part of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. One way to see that would be: Since $L/k$ is separable for any normal extension $N/k$ containing $L$ we have number of $k$ isomorphisms from $L\rightarrow N=[L:k]$. Now since $L/k$ is also normal we get number of $k$ automorphisms of $L=o(G)=L:k$